# How to set dynamic image path in pyqt5?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
 def setimage(self):
    self.image_label.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    filename = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'insert image', r'C:\Users\PristineSofts\Demo\Images','image (*.jpg *.png *.icon *.gif)')
    print(filename)
    self.image_label.setStyleSheet("QLabel{border:2px solid #d6d6d6;\n"
                                   "background-image:url(" +filename+ ");\n"
                                   "border-radius:30px;}\n")
```

I am trying to set image on label dynamically, but this code is not working for me. It shows path in the filename correctly, but it shows blank and window gets closed. I also used `QPixmap` but it not working.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a label you would do:

```
 # Make sure you load this library
 from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

 # And then this should work
 def setimage(self):
    filename = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'insert image', r'C:\Users\PristineSofts\Demo\Images','image (*.jpg *.png *.icon *.gif)')
    print("path is " + filename[0] " and I don't need " + filename[1])
    pngfile = QPixmap(filename[0]) # We create the image as a QPixmap widget, using your filename.
    self.image_label.setPixmap(pngfile) # And then we add it like this.
```

*Note:* If you still have issues, make sure you provide the path correctly. Also, you might need to do a `self.image_label.clear()` after your print.

**Edit:** Filename seems to be a tuple, so you need to choose what item from it you want. filename[0] would be the path string. filename[1] would be non-needed data image `(*.jpg *.png *.icon *.gif)`.

At python, you get data often in tuples, lists or dicts, and picking that data is easily done by specifying the index of that data `item[number of index]`. Note that indexes at python starts at 0, not at 1.

Example: If I want to pick `patata` in this list:

```
mytuple = ("something", "nothing", "patata", "test")
```

I would just use `mytuple[2]`, because the index [0] is `something`, the index [1] is `nothing`, `patata` is [2] and `test` is [3].

Comment: its not working also its not showing any error,any other solution.

Comment: Do you have the script and the images on the same folder? is `filename` a full path like `C:\something\images\myimage.png` or just `myimage.png`?

Comment: path like this('C:/Users/PristineSoft/Demo/Images/image.png', 'image (*.jpg *.png *.icon *.gif)'.images are in the subfolder

Comment: So when you do `print(filename)` the result is `('C:/Users/PristineSoft/Demo/Images/image.png', 'image (*.jpg *.png *.icon *.gif)'`? If that's the case, then the fix is as simple as split that tuple. See my updated code.

Comment: I'm glad we found the issue. Please remember to mark the answer as accepted, and upvote it on the left side arrows :P